# Bind columns of 2 different dataframes spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 different data frames in spark  and I'd like to bind their columns to form a unique data frame.  How can I do it using spark scala?
Thanks

Comment: If you could provide an example with input and output data would be very helpful

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to *join* two dataframes.

To do this you need to have a key that you will bind (join) the columns of a row/s with the columns of another row/s on. You can find more information here: https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/join-types-spark-sql/read

```
myDataframe
  .join(otherDataframe, col("x") === col("y"))
```

Comment: I do not want to make a join. I got 2 DFs with the same number of rows and I want append one to the right of the other one

Comment: I think a join will do exactly that

Comment: doesn't  join execute the cartesian product between the rows? and the you need to filter on key equality. What simply want to do is to concatenate the columns as they are.